# PHP: unwanted space in email form

Tags: php, forms

Each time the user press the 'send' button without entering any data in the form fields, one space is added to the 'name' field. The space is also added before the text if the user types something in this field and presses the 'send' button without filling the other fields.

I found out that if I remove the php code for the 'name' input tag, the space is gone.

I want to find out what has caused this, not to add code to empty the field, thanks.

Any help is appreciated to get rid of this space.

contact-form.php:

```
        <?php if( !empty($errors)) : ?>
            <div class="panel">  
                <ul><li><?php echo implode('</li><li>', $errors); ?></li></ul>
            </div>
            <script src="_scripts/scroll.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <form action="testing-email.php" method="post">
            <label>Name *<input type="text" placeholder="Insert your name here.." name="name" autocomplete="off"<?php echo isset($fields['name']) ? ' value= " '. e($fields['name']) . ' " ' : ''?>>
            </label>
            <label>Email *<input type="email" placeholder="Insert your email here.." name="email" autocomplete="off"<?php echo isset($fields['email']) ? ' value=" '. e($fields['email']) . ' " ' : ''?>>
            </label> 
            <label>Message *<textarea placeholder="Insert your message here.." name="message" rows="8"><?php echo isset($fields['message']) ? e($fields['message']) : ''?></textarea>
            </label>

            <input type="submit" value="Send" class="sendEmail">

            <br>
            <p class="muted">* means a required field</p>
        </form>
```

testing-email.php:

```
    foreach($fields as $field => $data) {
       if(empty($data)) {
           $errors[] = 'The ' . ucfirst($field) . ' field is required.';
       }
     }
```

main.css:

```
label, input, textarea {
display: block;
}
input, textarea {
padding: 5px;
font-size: 1em;
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
label input, label textarea {
font-size: 1em;
}
label {
margin-bottom: 14px;
text-align: left;
}
input[type="submit"], button {
width: 20%;
height: 50px;
font-size: 1.2em;
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
outline: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 50px;
border-radius: 50px;
border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.sendEmail:hover {
background-color: black;
color: white;
letter-spacing: .1em;
font-weight: bold;
}
.muted {
color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
text-align: left;
}
.panel {
color: red;
width: 50%;
text-align: left;
margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

Comment: You are adding spaces yourself: `... ? ' value= " '. e($fields['name']) . ' " ' : ...`, etc.. Just check the source code of the generated html to see what I mean.

Comment: I have tried to remove these spaces, but without any effect. Same spaces for the other fields, but no extra spaces in the form at all.

Comment: Thanks jeroen! silversunhunter answer is accepted because he has pointed to the exact place :)

Comment: Hmm.. It looks like your email input is formatted the same way in your question.

Comment: The 'type' in email input tag is set to 'email', therefore there is no unwanted space in the form in spite of the extra spaces in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeroen is right. You are adding spaces in your value:

```
value= " '. e($fields['name']) . ' " ' : ''
```

change to:

```
value= "'. e($fields['name']) . '"' : ''
```

Comment: Actually, you are right. Thanks :) But strangely same error in the email input tag but there is no extra space in the form?!

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra space in this line:

```
<label>Name *<input type="text" placeholder="Insert your name here.." name="name" autocomplete="off"<?php echo isset($fields['name']) ? ' value= " '. e($fields['name']) . ' " ' : ''?>>
```

Replace it for this one:

```
<label>Name *<input type="text" placeholder="Insert your name here.." name="name" autocomplete="off"<?php echo isset($fields['name']) ? ' value="'. e($fields['name']) . '" ' : ''?>>
```

Comment: Don't you see there is an extra space between (value= ") and (value=")?

Comment: I did not. But that is not the cause of the OP's problem so this will not solve it.

Comment: That space has nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: Guys, what is going on here? I posted the same solution that the one that was chosen as the best answer and I got a  -1.

Comment: Your answer is not correct as that space has nothing to do with the issue here. See silversunhunter answer for more info about where to remove the space in the code. I don't have enough reputation to add or remove points.

Comment: You are right, I removed another white space. I feel useless.

Comment: @PabloDigiani Don't take it personal :-)